# como abrir una nueva instancia y cerrar la instancia anterior en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quisiera su ayuda en c# Windows form.

Quiero que cada vez que abra mi aplicación (desde: un acceso directo) o (desde: myaplicacion.exe) la instancia anterior que esta abierta se cierre y solo quede abierta la nueva instancia intento crear un reproductor de música y cuando reproduzco una canción desde explorer.exe o desde un mp3 la canción se reproduce gracias ala condicional Environment.CommandLine.Contains el problema esta en que si intento abrir otra canción desde explorer.exe la aplicación se abre de nuevo y se empiezan a reproducir las dos canciones al mismo tiempo por que ambas instancias están abiertas ya logre hacer que solo se abra una sola instancia gracias a una condicional de Mutex pero no tengo como mandar los datos de Environment.CommandLine.Contains a la instancia anterior así que pensé que una solución mas sencilla seria cerrar la instancia anterior y abrir una nueva pero no encuentro información, tal vez por que no se como buscar algo así.

```
bool activo;
System.Threading.Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "tonyyy1",out activo);

if (!activo) //siesta activo la app nueva se cierra
{
    Application.Exit();
}
else
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new tonyyy1());
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias echarle un vistazo a este [enlace](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-weekly-source-code-31-single-instance-winforms-and-microsoftvisualbasicdll). Lo que hace aqui es tener una aplicación que sólo te permite tener una instancia, y cuando la intentas abrir de nuevo estando ejecutandose, te redirije a la instancia ya existente